# PHP edit JSON MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need some help, I can't get it done...

I have a database, called "db"
Inside I have a table named "objects"
In this table there is a column named "details" which contain a JSON [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMMbt.png)

In a PHP script I want to edit the "cost" parameters based on the value of the "type" and the other parameter named "source" to keep his value.

For example, if type is small -> cost = 1
type = big -> cost = 2.

Any ideas?

I have tried several but I received warning:

Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object
Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: If `cost` value is defined by `type` value then this relation must be stored in separate table, and only type identifier must be stored in current table. Read something about normalization..

Comment: Most likely, you need to convert the JSON string to an object using `json_decode(json, false)` before accessing its properties.

Comment: I have tried this @phatfingers and I receive this warning, and in database is the following: error (https://i.imgur.com/iJB3mCq.png), database (https://i.imgur.com/qoxQHA7.png)

Comment: You need to add code for 1. how you decode the JSON, and 2. how you attempt to change it.

Comment: I have tried with the following code (https://i.imgur.com/6f5TTJ6.png) and I receive this error "
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\func\preturi.php on line 12"

Comment: Please read about SQL-Injections. Do not use vars in SQL queries. (Also your are using `objects` in 1st, and `object` in 2nd query.)

Comment: @plezhh There are multiple ways to fetch queries.  I think if you scroll down to the examples on https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php, you'll find one that matches your style.

Answer (score 0):

To edit the JSON data in the details column you would have to first decode the JSON like so:

```
$query //This be equal to your query data from the db containing the table data

$json = $query["details"];

$d_coded_json = json_decode($json);

if($d_coded_json->type == "small"){
 $d_coded_json->cost = 1;
}else if ($d_coded_json->type == "big"){
  $d_coded_json->cost = 2;
}

// you can convert to back to json by running the code below

$new_json = json_encode($d_coded_json);

// save back to db
```

Comment: I have tried with the following code (i.imgur.com/6f5TTJ6.png) and I receive this error " Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\func\preturi.php on line 12"

Comment: That error means you are querying the mysqli_result as an object and not an array, in that note `$json = $query["details"];` change to  `$json = $query->details;`